# Selenium printing

Tags: java, selenium

```
public void Check() {       
    String[] List = new String[3];
    PageSource = driver.getPageSource();

    List[0]= "Test1";
    List[1]= "Test2";
    List[2]= "Test3";

    for (int count = 0; count < List.length; count++) {
        if (PageSource.equals(List)) {
            System.out.println(List); 
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Match"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Example: The string from the PageSource is "Test1".

Exepected output:

Test1

Hi, I wanted to just display the string that matched with the string that I'll get from the PageSource.  I only want the match printed, if there is no match, "No Match" should be printed. In short, I want to search from all the strings in the array if the string from the PageSource has a match. Please let me know what should I change or add with my code. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear from your code what you are trying to do. You are searching for something in the page source... what is it you want to search for and what do you want printed if the string is found or not found? Please describe what you want your scenario to accomplish.

Comment: Hi JeffC, for example, the PageSource contains "Passed". I will compare it to the values from my Hashmap and will output the string value from it if matched.

Comment: What is the purpose of the "1" and "2" portions of the `HashMap`? I posted an answer based on your code with some tweaks. See if that helps.

Comment: This update doesn't really help. If you only want the match printed then why do you have the `else` where you print "No Match"? So, what do you actually want? Do you *only* want the match printed? Should "No Match" be printed if a match isn't found? Should it stop on the first match or print all matches? Please spend a few minutes and think about the scenario and add some more details.

Comment: @JeffC I think it is clear now. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

i think if your Page Source contains the specific value you are searching, your integer code is always going to print a numeric value. code is printing value of "foundKey" which is a integer in your case, you can change the below line code according to your need:

```
 System.out.println(foundKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is ok if you just want to print what you want to find.
For example if you want to find "Invalid data", do this:

```
message.put("Invalid data","anything");
```

But it may still print the int value because you use 'break' after the first match.

So you can use ArrayList to replace HashMap for the type of "message". It's easier to iterate the target values.And if you still use 'break', you can put "Invalid data" as the first element of the message.

Comment: Hi, I'm planning to change it to this one:public void Check()
 {
  
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 PageSource = driver.getPageSource();
 Set<String> set=new HashSet<String>(list);

    
    list.add("Passed");
    list.add("Invalid");
    
     for (String str : set)
     {
        if (PageSource.equals(list))
        {
        
  System.out.println(list.get(set)); 
        }
     }break;
        
        else
        {
         System.out.println("No Match"); 
        }
 
} Can you help me what's wrong with this?

Comment: Why NOT just use ArrayList?  Why do do want to use Set？

Comment: Hi, i am now using arraylist. I used the code that JeffC put here. However it prints all the values in the arraylist. Not sure why.

Comment: When contains, his code will print "Invalid Data:XXX".  And When not contains, his code will print "No Match:XXX" . The result is all right.What result do you want to get?

Comment: I just want to print the value that only matched. Not the whole set of strings :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a simpler way to accomplish this. I would do something more like

EDIT: This new code will find the first instance of a string from the List and quits searching on the first found string.

```
public static void Message()
{
    PageSource = driver.getPageSource();

    // set up Array of search strings
    List<String> searchText = new ArrayList<String>();
    searchText.add("Test1");
    searchText.add("Test2");
    searchText.add("Test3");

    // loop through Array looking for each string contained
    for (String text : searchText)
    {
        if (PageSource.contains(text))
        {
            System.out.println("Found: <" + text + ">");
            return;
        }
    }

    System.err.println("No Match");
}
```

Comment: It prints all strings in the list. Maybe because you're doing it under the for loop?

Comment: You need to describe your scenario in detail. You haven't done that yet which is leading to confusion on what you are trying to do and answers that don't meet your criteria. Once you post an updated question with details on your scenario, I will update my answer.

Comment: I have updated my question. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: OK. This should now do what you want.